# How to show session from one view to another

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I have tried to accessing session from one view to another view using ASP.NET Core 6. The session displays ok in the `Index` view, but did not show in `ChangePassword` view. Please assist me the session to show in the `ChangePassword` view.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Name = HttpContext.Session.GetString("username");
    return View();
}
```

Index view:

```
<h4> Hello: @ViewBag.Name </h4>
```

```
public IActionResult ChangePassword()
{
    ViewBag.Email = HttpContext.Session.GetString("username");
    return View();
}
```

`ChangePassword` view:

```
<input type="text" value="@ViewBag.Name" />
```

```
public IActionResult Login(Login model)
{
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("username", “Dauda”);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Student");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> < input type="text" value="@ViewBag.Name" />

In your ChangePassword view, you use `@ViewBag.Name` not `@ViewBag.Email` , so change your  ChangePassword action like:

```
public IActionResult ChangePassword()
{
    ViewBag.Name = HttpContext.Session.GetString("username");
    return View();
}
```

result:

[image]